# theme() from Tailwind is not recognized

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css

I know it may be a silly question but I cannot find the answer anywhere.
I'm using Tailwind with CRA and CSS modules.

I've overwritten the default theme colors to my own ones.
When I try to use the colors inside my CSS modules like this,

```
.amountSign {
    color: theme('colors.pink');
}
```

it seems like theme() is not recognized and in the browser the property value seems to be invalid.

[image]

Should I import something from somewhere to make theme() recognizable? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. I'm assuming it has something to do with the `postcss.config.js`

Comment: I still have this problem. Did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind's [functions and directives](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives) only work if your CSS is proccessed by Tailwind.

From what you've shared it looks like your CSS modules aren't ran through Tailwind and so Tailwind's `theme()` function is never compiled down to pure CSS.

[This blog](https://dev.to/ryandunn/how-to-use-tailwind-with-create-react-app-and-postcss-with-no-hassle-2i09) outlines the steps for using Tailwind with CRA.